# How is Y森飯ルド romanized?

Tags: translation, meaning, rōmaji

A little context:

This is the name of a rather obscure Japanese band. The lead singer goes by the name of Yasue Dangerous Ojisan (ヤスエでんじゃらすおじさん) and [this is his blog](http://ydo2438.jimdo.com/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB/).

Record label and retailer Tower Records [lists (or listed)](https://www.google.ro/search?q=tower+YASUE+DANGEROUS+OJISAN) the name as "Y MORIIIRUDO". Google Translate romanizes the kanji [as "morimeshi"](https://translate.google.com/#ja/en/Y%E6%A3%AE%E9%A3%AF%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89).

I'm not well-versed with kanji, and I'm not sure if it's a play on words, an abbreviation, both, or none. This may be silly, but ルド at the end might even stand for "`ld`" (e.g. フィールド → fiirudo → field).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, ignore whatever Google says about words it doesn't recognize. Each kanji can have lots of readings, and Google is very bad at giving a reasonable guess about uncommon proper nouns.

Second, Y森飯ルド is a very odd-looking word even to native Japanese speakers. Neither 森飯 nor ルド is a common Japanese word. It may be some sort of wordplay, but I have almost no idea what it means. It may or may not be related to rice fields.

Such a strange word usually comes with a furigana, but apparently they want to keep the reading a secret. [This page](http://www.yodobashi.com/NO-FUN-ISSUE-01/pd/100000009002460296/) also lists the band's name as "Y MORIIIRUDO", so probably this is the correct reading (ワイ・モリイールド  or ワイ・モリイイルド in katakana). But the only way to make sure is to ask that dangerous ojisan.

---

**EDIT**: Apparently this band name is an initialism:

- Y comes from Yasue Dangerous Ojisan
- 森 comes from [大森靖子](https://twitter.com/oomoriseiko/status/447761025379495936) (Ōmori Seiko)
- 飯 comes from [飯田裕](https://twitter.com/seba_iida/status/506422186551177216) (Iida Yutaka <del>Iida Yu? Iida Hiroshi?</del>)
- ルド ... I couldn't identify him/her

So "Y MORIIIRUDO" seems reasonable.

Comment: Damn, that's some fine observation skill. Building up on what you said, ルド probably comes from セクシーワイルド, drummer for a band called [The××ズ](https://www.facebook.com/Thechomechome20xx). Also a little correction, it's [Iida Yutaka](https://www.tochoh.com/performer/P2402).